# using @selector in a class IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, class, selector

Im making a class that creates a timer that then calls a void using @selector or (SEL). The app crashes when [mytimer timer…]; is called because "unknown selector called". The error is that it isnt finding the void I'm giving to it but i know that the void works fine. My question is how to I write the myselector part correctly?

```
+ (void) timer:(NSTimer*)timer interval:(int)interval selector:(SEL)myselector   
{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                         target:self
                                       selector:myselector
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
}
```

This is the method being implemented:

```
[mytimer timer:NameOfTimerTheWorks interval:0.1 selector:@selector(myVoid)];

... 

- (void)myVoid
{
Do stuff
}
```

Also I understand that this class looks completely useless but there is more to it that I didnt include. My problem revolves around the selector.

Comment: where is the myselector coming from, the parameter is just selector?  Additionally, that is a class function, and it looks like you are trying to call it on an instance "mytimer"

Comment: Please fix your snippets so that they are valid code; you seems to be using two different names for the same thing in the first, and have a method with no name in the second. Also explain in more detail what "does not work" means.

Comment: Yes I edited it incorrectly. I belive I fixed it.

Comment: What "it" isn't "finding" your method? Do you have a compilation error, or does something happen when you build and run your program? If the former, what's the _exact text_ of the error? If the latter, _what happens_?

Comment: When ever [mytimer timer...]; is called I get the error: unknown selector called. In this case it is when I press a button.

Comment: you're getting unknown selector because `self` in your +timer method is not an instance of your class, it's a reference to the class. Refactor your code as I've suggested and see if it works. There's potentially bigger issues though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your use of @selector(), your issue is with Objective C classes, and what `self` means in different scopes.

The problem is that you're creating your timer in a class `+` method and `self` at that point is not the instance you want, it's actually the `Class` itself. I wouldn't be doing it in a class method, but if you must, just pass in the reference to the target and it should send th message your'e expecting.

Change your implementation to the following so you pass in the target, and return the timer

```
+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTarget:(id)target 
     interval:(int)interval 
     selector:(SEL)myselector   
{
  return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                           target:target
                                         selector:myselector
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
}


NameOfTimerTheWorks = [mytimer timetWithTarget:self interval:0.1 selector:@selector(myVoid)];

- (void)myVoid
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

Additionally, in Objective C the standard way to name classes is with a capital letter, and camel case where appropriate. Your class should be `MyTimer` and not `mytimer` and iVars are lowercase eg `nameOfTimerTheWorks`.

Comment: `timer` is one of the parameters in that method; that assignment seems like it's probably intended to reassign the pointer that is passed in, but of course is doing no such thing.

Comment: @TannerQuigley how so? If NameOfTimerTheWorks is an instance variable of something, you can call [NameOfTimerTheWorks invalidate] where you need to. There's plenty of ways to invalidate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to access an instance level method using a class level method.

I changed + to - so that it was an instance level method.

If you wanted your method to be class level it would require that you make the method you want to call also class level.

```
- /* <-- + */(void) timer:(NSTimer*)timer interval:(int)interval selector:(SEL)selector   
{

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                         target:self
                                       selector:selector
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

}
```